# Bibliotecas HTTP/Servidor HTTP

Tags: servidor, http, cliente-servidor, lado-do-servidor

Minha duvida é sobre servidores web e bibliotecas voltada para o protocolo **HTTP**.

No PHP você pode usar o "apache" como servidor web, mas em outras linguagens é utilizado o mesmo stack? Essa duvida me veio ao pesquisar linguagens como: **Go**, **Crystal**, **Hack**, **Ruby** e **Python**.

Vi que nelas tem bibliotecas voltadas para o protocolo **HTTP**, nelas você cria seu próprio servidor web, servindo a si mesma ou é um complemento ao apache(por exemplo)?

Seria como você criar sua própria estrutura de "requisições", moldando conforme sua necessidade?

Sempre mantive essa duvida, sei que sempre vai precisar de um servidor web, porem não sei se sempre vai ser encaixar o apache ou nginx(os que eu conheço).

## Exemplo:

```
 Código tirado do site: cystal-lang.org
 
 require "http/server"

 server = HTTP::Server.new(8080) do |context|
  context.response.content_type = "text/plain"
  context.response.print "Hello world, got #{context.request.path}!"
 end

puts "Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080"
server.listen
```

Grato

Comment: O Apache é uma das opções. Você poderia usar PHP no Nginx, no Lighthttpd e mais uma infinidade de servidores (e para testes, até o PHP sozinho). Funciona até no IIS, apesar de não ser uma combinação das melhores. Quanto a criar uma estrutura própria, só depende da finalidade. Eu tenho coisas rodando em PHP, mas para algumas coisas mais pontuais, fiz um servidor próprio, para performance maior. É um executável único, que faz toda a parte HTTP, e a lógica de funcionamento. Mesma coisa para Websockets. Preferi um próprio para facilitar a integração com outras coisas minhas.

Comment: Detalhe: nada impediria de eu fazer requisições para o PHP no meu próprio servidor via CGI ou coisa do tipo. O HTTP é um protocolo extremamente simples. O cuidado está nos detalhes, e é trabalhoso cuidar de cache e modificação de arquivos, mas sem grandes segredos. HTTPS é mais chatinho, mas tem bibliotecas abertas para isso

Comment: Entendi, o php foi um exemplo, porque nao vi nada relacionado em criar seu próprio servidor nele, sempre apache ou outros. No caso de outras linguagens, isso se assume? Ou eu tenho que criar um servidor próprio, ex em ruby ou go, já que elas tem bibliotecas HTTP e a maioria dos exemplos é, "olha como é simples criar um servidor http".

Comment: Isso varia bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Não seria como o Apache visto que servidores embutidos são bastante limitados, servidores completos como Apache possuem inúmeras configurações e recursos extras que os servidores embutidos não tem. Geralmente eles servem para testes rápidos ou implementações simplistas. O próprio PHP possui um servidor embutido, você pode ativar esse recurso executando o seguinte comando:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Para entender o comando acima melhor [leia essa página](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Correto, eu compreendo a diferença entre os servidores embutidos ou ate mesmo os pacotes como xampp e etc. A duvida em si, esta fora do contexto php e sim em um contexto geral. O que eu quis dizer: No PHP pode se utilizar o "apache" como servidor web(produção), mas e nas outras linguagens ? PHP tem essa "facilidade" de se rodar os scripts(foi o que eu li em pesquisas). Me veio essa duvida pelo fato de certas linguagens como "ruby" tem uma biblioteca voltada para o protocolo http. Você desenvolveria seu proprio servidor ou ainda precisaria de rodar um servidor como apache?

Comment: Cada linguagem tem seu servidor, no Python você pode suar Apache ou lighttpd ou mesmo NGINX. O Ruby tem o Puma Web Server. Desta forma cada linguagem tem seu servidor de produção, e tb praticamente todas tem servidores embutidos para pequenos testes

Comment: No caso, então essas bibliotecas HTTP são para desenvolver servidores embutidos para uso no desenvolvimento? Tipo a biblioteca a HTTP da Go ou Ruby.

Comment: Em grande parte sim, pois elas não possuem recursos avançados para lidar com muitos acessos ou mesmo grande segurança em termos de acesso a arquivos em disco.